# Activerecord - Is count better or limit better?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Say, I want to find if a user has atleast 3 orders

Which is better considering orders table is quite huge ?

a. Limit the size of resultset to 3 and see if the size matches

```
NO_OF_MATCHES = 3
orders =  Order.where('user_id = ?', 1).limit(NO_OF_MATCHES )
return true if orders.size == NO_OF_MATCHES
```

b. Just get a count and compare against that

```
NO_OF_MATCHES = 3
count = Order.count(:conditions => ['user_id = ?',1])
return true if count >= NO_OF_MATCHES
```

Any totally new method that I have not thought of would also be welcome

Comment: The first one does `select orders.*` the second `count(*)`. Just don't query information you don't need. If you don't need any of the data the first one returns, use the second one (yes, it will probably be faster in a table with a lot of columns)

Comment: You don't need to use `return` since the last value will automatically be returned by the method. Also, since `count >= NO_OF_MATCHES` is an expression that returns either `true` or `false`, you don't need the `true if ...`.

Comment: I just need the boolean value whether there are atleast 3 results or not. So, I take it that option b is better for this.. even considering the number of rows in orders is a lot (not columns).

Comment: It's not about just expensive queries. Why fetch ALL of the orders information when you don't need ANY of it? Think of it logically, if you only need the count, only grab the count. If you only needed the id in a query, only select the id :)

Comment: Note that i am only fetching 3 results, not all.. was only wondering whether fetching 3 results is faster or counting a million records is faster .. hence i brought the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Note that i am only fetching 3 results, not all.. was only wondering whether fetching 3 results is faster or counting a million records is faster .. hence i brought the question."

I will plus-one ~eveevans answer, but here's the long answer...

Often, a database will keep a count of the number of records and optimize the results of the query to just use the number.  Sometimes they keep the number of distinct values, number of records for values with unique indexes, or any number of cases dependent of the database vendor's implementation.  Your query just might happen to hit on a number they are tracking and the optimizer can use.  So count(*) queries can very often be faster then selects.

Next, with a "SELECT count(*)" there is one row with one integer column, which is a *lot* less data than a result set with a "SELECT *".  The database has to get the value of all the fields in the record.  (Doing a "SELECT id FROM orders LIMIT 3" would even help.)  It has to byte encode each fields value for each of the records.  Then the client adapter has to decode the bytes into a ruby value.  Then ActiveRecord goes through the description of the columns and builds the attributes array.  It's a lot less work with just the count.

Answer (score 2):

Use the option B if you only want a number (count), 
the first case return you all the Orders that match the condition, the second one returns you only the number of orders that match the condition.